# Connection refused on django cache socket

Tags: django, sockets, caching

I've setup a cache as defined in documentation like this:

```
CACHES = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'django_redis.cache.RedisCache',
        'LOCATION': [
            'redis://127.0.0.1:6379',
        ],
        'TIMEOUT': None,
    }
}
```

Now I try to access it in my website and I receive this error:

```
ConnectionError at /exchange/provider
Error 10061 connecting to 127.0.0.1:6379. No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/exchange/provider
Django Version: 2.0.2
Exception Type: ConnectionError
Exception Value:    
Error 10061 connecting to 127.0.0.1:6379. No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
Exception Location: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\lib\site-packages\redis\connection.py in connect, line 489
Python Executable:  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\python.exe
Python Version: 3.6.4
Python Path:    
['C:\\Users\\sdres\\Documents\\Django\\github_repo\\32018\\innovatorsedge',
 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual '
 'Studio\\Shared\\Python36_64\\python36.zip',
 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\Shared\\Python36_64\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\Shared\\Python36_64\\lib',
 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\Shared\\Python36_64',
 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual '
 'Studio\\Shared\\Python36_64\\lib\\site-packages',
 'C:\\Users\\sdres\\Documents\\Django\\github_repo\\32018\\innovatorsedge']
Server time:    Thu, 22 Mar 2018 18:16:13 -0700
Error during template rendering
In template C:\Users\sdres\Documents\Django\github_repo\32018\innovatorsedge\common\templates\common\base.html, error at line 0

Error 10061 connecting to 127.0.0.1:6379. No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
1   {% include "common/header.html" %}
2   {% block content %}{% endblock %}
3   {% include "common/footer.html" %}
Traceback Switch to copy-and-paste view
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\lib\site-packages\django_redis\cache.py in _decorator
            return method(self, *args, **kwargs) ...
▶ Local vars
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\lib\site-packages\django_redis\cache.py in get
                                   client=client) ...
▶ Local vars
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\lib\site-packages\django_redis\client\default.py in get
            raise ConnectionInterrupted(connection=client, parent=e) ...
▶ Local vars
During handling of the above exception (Redis ConnectionError: Error 10061 connecting to 127.0.0.1:6379. No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.), another exception occurred:
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py in inner
            response = get_response(request) ...
▶ Local vars
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py in _get_response
                response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request) ...
▶ Local vars
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py in _get_response
                response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs) ...
▶ Local vars
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\decorators.py in _wrapped_view
                return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs) ...
▶ Local vars
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\cache.py in _wrapped_view_func
        response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs) ...
▶ Local vars
C:\Users\sdres\Documents\Django\github_repo\32018\innovatorsedge\matching\views.py in provider_dashboard_view
    return render(request, 'matching/provider-dashboard.html', context) ...
▶ Local vars
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\lib\site-packages\django\shortcuts.py in render
    content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, request, using=using) ...
▶ Local vars
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader.py in render_to_string
    return template.render(context, request) ...
▶ Local vars
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\lib\site-packages\django\template\backends\django.py in render
            return self.template.render(context) ...
▶ Local vars
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py in render
                    return self._render(context) ...
▶ Local vars
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py in _render
        return self.nodelist.render(context) ...
▶ Local vars
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py in render
                bit = node.render_annotated(context) ...
▶ Local vars
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py in render_annotated
            return self.render(context) ...
▶ Local vars
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py in render
            return compiled_parent._render(context) ...
▶ Local vars
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py in _render
        return self.nodelist.render(context) ...
▶ Local vars
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py in render
                bit = node.render_annotated(context) ...
▶ Local vars
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py in render_annotated
            return self.render(context) ...
▶ Local vars
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py in render
                result = block.nodelist.render(context) ...
▶ Local vars
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py in render
                bit = node.render_annotated(context) ...
▶ Local vars
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py in render_annotated
            return self.render(context) ...
▶ Local vars
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\lib\site-packages\django\templatetags\cache.py in render
        value = fragment_cache.get(cache_key) ...
▶ Local vars
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\lib\site-packages\django_redis\cache.py in _decorator
            raise e.parent ...
▶ Local vars
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\lib\site-packages\django_redis\client\default.py in get
            value = client.get(key) ...
▶ Local vars
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\lib\site-packages\redis\client.py in get
        return self.execute_command('GET', name) ...
▶ Local vars
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\lib\site-packages\redis\client.py in execute_command
            connection.send_command(*args) ...
▶ Local vars
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\lib\site-packages\redis\connection.py in send_command
        self.send_packed_command(self.pack_command(*args)) ...
▶ Local vars
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\lib\site-packages\redis\connection.py in send_packed_command
            self.connect() ...
▶ Local vars
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\lib\site-packages\redis\connection.py in connect
            raise ConnectionError(self._error_message(e))
```

I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong, I'm able to access my normal 8000 socket just fine and connect to my database, but as soon as I navigate to a page that's using a cache I get this error. Please help, most other documentation discusses emails and the only one I found related to django cache isn't answered.

Thanks,

Comment: could you type "telnet 127.0.0.1 6379" to cmd.

Answer (score 0):

I realized I was using an older version redis. I upgraded to 3.2 and it works fine now.